# Any idea how to approach this problem

Tags: education, area

A rectangular meadow will have a fence around it. The long side is $130$ m longer than the short side. The sides lengths can be written $x$ and $x+ 130$. Write a simplified expression for 1) circumference 2) area
any idea will be helpful .

Comment: Do you know how to find perimeter and area of a rectangle in general?

Comment: Do you know how to write down the formulas for the perimeter and area of a rectangle?

Comment: yes i know how find perimeter and area of a rectangle in general?

Comment: So what would they be?

Comment: can i solve it using just perimeter and area of a rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\text{Circumference}=2(x + x + 130)= 4x+260$

$\text{Area}=(x+130)\cdot (x)=x^2 + 130x = x^2 + 130x + 65^2 - 65^2 = (x+65+\sqrt{65})(x+65-\sqrt{65})$

Comment: I'm impressed where does 2(x+x+130) come from ?

Comment: The circumference of the meadow here means the perimeter.

Comment: what about area ?

Comment: We can use the form a²-b²=(a+b)(a-b)

Comment: Check your last statement about area.

Comment: it's the right answer ?

Comment: @AmineMontasir You can always check answers. Try $x=0$ or $x=1$ and  confirm the results.

Comment: fence is a circle

Comment: The radius of the fence will be the half of the smaller side.